# Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialized

Tags: android, testing, webdriver-io

I've been trying to do a test on webdriverio, but without success. a simple test with page objects I don't know if I'm making a mistake in the import or it's something in the configuration

https://github.com/brugdev/teste_android

```
import { expect }  from '@wdio/globals'
import homePage from '../pageobjects/home.page'
import loginPage from '../pageobjects/login.page'
import profilePage from '../pageobjects/profile.page'



describe('Abrir o Aplicativo', () => {
    
    it('Deve abrir o app aguarda 10 segundo e sair', async () => {
        await driver.pause(10000)
        await homePage.openMenu('profile')//abrir o menu detalhes pageobjects homepage
        await loginPage.login('cliente@ebac.art.br','GD*peToHNJ1#c$sgk08EaYJQ')//preencher email e senha detalhes page objects login
        await homePage.openMenu('profile')
        expect ((await profilePage.ProfileName('EBAC Cliente')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy()
        await driver.pause(10000)//Aguardando 10 segundos aplicativo

    })
})
```

Log ERRO

```
0-0] 2024-03-19T02:06:14.073Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialized.
[0-0] `browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
[0-0] Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.
[0-0] Spec file(s): file:///C:/repositorio/Test_mobile_novo/test/specs/login.test.js
[0-0] Error: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\test\pageobjects\home.page' imported from C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\test\specs\login.test.js
[0-0]     at finalizeResolution (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366:11)
[0-0]     at moduleResolve (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:801:10)
[0-0]     at Object.defaultResolve (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:912:11)
[0-0]     at C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:218:35
[0-0]     at entrypointFallback (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:168:34)
[0-0]     at C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:217:14
[0-0]     at addShortCircuitFlag (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:409:21)
[0-0]     at resolve (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:197:12)
[0-0]     at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:865:28)
[0-0]     at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:303:30)
[0-0]     at MochaAdapter._loadFiles (file:///C:/repositorio/Test_mobile_novo/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:91:35)
[0-0]     at async MochaAdapter.init (file:///C:/repositorio/Test_mobile_novo/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:66:9)
[0-0]     at async Object.adapterFactory.init (file:///C:/repositorio/Test_mobile_novo/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:222:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (file:///C:/repositorio/Test_mobile_novo/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:83:27)
[0-0]  Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialized.     
`browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.
Spec file(s): file:///C:/repositorio/Test_mobile_novo/test/specs/login.test.js
Error: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\test\pageobjects\home.page' imported from C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\test\specs\login.test.js
    at finalizeResolution (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366:11)
    at moduleResolve (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:801:10)
    at Object.defaultResolve (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:912:11)
    at C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:218:35
    at entrypointFallback (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:168:34)
    at C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:217:14
    at addShortCircuitFlag (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:409:21)
    at resolve (C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:197:12)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:865:28)
    at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:303:30)
[0-0] 2024-03-19T02:06:14.078Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()
[0-0] 2024-03-19T02:06:14.080Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://0.0.0.0:4723/session/6f0f1396-276b-41b7-ac17-e72116080c48       
[0-0] 2024-03-19T02:06:15.284Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null
[0-0] FAILED in Android - file:///C:/repositorio/Test_mobile_novo/test/specs/login.test.js
2024-03-19T02:06:15.430Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2024-03-19T02:06:15.430Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:26

2024-03-19T02:06:15.432Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2024-03-19T02:06:15.688Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2024-03-19T02:06:15.689Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
PS C:\repositorio\Test_mobile_novo>
```

I tried to do a simple test to access an apk